# Multiple Statements in mysql2 - nodejs

Tags: node.js, mysql2, node-mysql2

I'm using [mysql2](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mysql2) in my nodejs project, in [mysql](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mysql) library i used Multiple Statements for update my database and that works great, but for some reason in mysql2 it doesn't work, i googled it a lot and didn't found any solution, does mysql2 not support in multple statements??

- Here's the multiple query

  ```
  async function updateChannels(dtz) {
  for (const data of dtz) {
    multipleQuery += `UPDATE myTable SET data='${data.newData}' WHERE data='${data.oldData}';`
  }
  await con.execute(multipleQuery);}
  ```

In mysql.createConnection i added  **multipleStatements: true**

- Here's the error

UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'UPDATE

**That query working great when i copy and paste it in the phpMyAdmin console**

Comment: might you provide the error you get?

Comment: Are you getting any error? because it supports multiple statements query.

Comment: of course, sorry, i edited the question

Comment: help anyone? =_=

Comment: Works well for me. Try to double check that multipleStatements belongs to the `con`.

Answer (score 4):

You would need to use the query call instead of execute:

```
let rows, field;
try {
  [rows, fields] = await connection.query(query);
} catch (err) {
  // handle err
}
if (rows) {
  // exploit the result
}
```

But otherwise, yes, the execute command will let you run only a single instruction.

Answer (score 0):

Resolved [Issue](https://github.com/sidorares/node-mysql2/issues/386) on GitHub:

> You can't prepare query with multiple statements. Split it in two or use non-prepared statements api ( `dbpool.query(...)` )